# Spring MVC Converter and Swagger doc: how to?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I use converters in my Spring MCV controllers. In this example, the `String` from the path variable is mapped into a `UserId`:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/user/{user-id}")
public User get(@Parameter(description = "User id", required = true, example = "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6")
                @PathVariable("user-id")
                UserId userId) {
    return userService.get(userId)
}
```

It seems to annoy Swagger as the generated doc requires an object as parameter and not a plain string:

```
...
"/api/v1/user/{user-id}": {
  "get": {
    "operationId": "get",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "user-id",
          "in": "path",
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/UserId"
          },
        }
      ],
...
```

with the `UserId` schema:

```
"UserId": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "value": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "uuid"
    }
  }
}
```

And thus the Swagger UI cannot be used because either the parameter is considered as invalid when a single string is provided, either the data is actually invalid when the object format is used.

What is an option to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that, the `schema` parameter of the `@Parameter` annotation is the answer.

The above example becomes:

```java
@Parameter(description = "User id", 
           required = true, 
           schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class), // this is new
           example = "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6")
```